# How to start a new iteration within a loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, systemc

In the following `SystemC` `SC_THREAD` I'm trying to do the following: `image_buffer` is a 3 lines x 720 columns matrix which is filled with the bytes incoming from the port `p_in`. When the `image_buffer` has 2 lines and the first 5 bytes filled it must start copying the bytes into another matrix called `img`, whose size is 576 lines x 720 columns. The byte is saved just if it the signal `h_in` is `true`. When `img` is complete an image in format png will be generated. The problem I have with the code I wrote is that `i` and `j` are always 2 and 4 respectively, just the 2 first lines and the 4 pixels of the third line are saved un the image. Could you please give me a hint on how could I implement this?

```
void FILTER::filtering(){

    while(1){

        while(!h_in) wait(h_in.posedge_event());    

        for(i=0; i<3; i++){
            for(j=0; j<720; j++){
                image_buffer.pixel[i*image_buffer.width+j] = p_in;
                wait();
                while(!h_in) wait();

            //Begin of the block code I'm trying to test with
            if ( (i > 1) && (j > 3) ){      
                for(int bi=0; bi<576; bi++){
                    for(int bj=0; bj<720; bj++){
                        if (bi < 3){
                            img.pixel[bi*img.width+bj] = image_buffer.pixel[bi*image_buffer.width+bj];
                        }
                        else{
                            img.pixel[bi*img.width+bj] = image_buffer.pixel[(bi%3)*image_buffer.width+bj];
                        }

                        cout << "i: " << i << " j: " << j << endl;

                        if ( (bi == 575)&&(bj == 719) ){
                            image_write( &img, "test.png" );
                            exit(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            wait();
            //End of the block code I'm trying to test with

            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Update**
I have modified the code as follows, but when I do it the new counters `bi` and `bj` are always `0`:

```
while(1){

    while(!h_in) wait(h_in.posedge_event());    

    k = 0;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<720; j++){
            image_buffer.pixel[i*image_buffer.width+j] = p_in;
            wait();
            while(!h_in) wait();

            if( (i == 2 )&&(j > 4) ){

                for(bi=i-2; bi<576; i++){
                    for(bj=j-5; bj<720; j++){
                            cout << "bi: " << bi << "   bj: " << bj << endl;
                            img.pixel[bi*img.width+bj] = image_buffer.pixel[bi*image_buffer.width+bj];
                    }
                }

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need the second for loop at all,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a single thread solution, you would loop through the dimensions of the final image, and track `(row,col)` and a calculated `(bufrow,bufcol)`. You may not want to use for loops for this, since you will have iterations that can increment either the image position and the buffer position. Each iteration can have one of these conditions:

1. Buffer is initially filling - `(bufrow,bufcol)` increment,
   `(row,col)` do not
2. Buffer is filling and copying to image - `h`
   is true && `(bufrow,bufcol)` has surpassed (2,5) at some point
   (sticky buffer_is_ready indicator)
3. Buffer is not filling (`!h`),
   but copying to image is occuring - increment `(row,col)`

You'll probably want a `while(row<576&&col<720)` as your only loop (inside the while(1)). In each iteration, handle the increments of the (row,col) and (bufrow,bufcol) manually. Don't forget the buffer wraparound:

```
  if (h) {
    bufrow = (bufcol == 719 && bufrow == 2) ? 0 
             (bufcol == 719)                ? bufrow+1 : bufrow;
    bufcol = (bufcol == 719) ? 0 : bufcol+1;
  }
```

It could also simplify the code to use a two thread solution. Using two threads can also decouple the buffer filling from any computing and copying to the final image.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you don't want to loop over the second array you are copying to.  You need to track a second set of indexing variables that are incremented based on the outer loop.

```
int ii, jj
for i = 0 to n
  for j = 0 to m
    if i > v and j > u  
      img[ii,jj] = val
      ++ii, ++jj
```